# OOP object instantiating

Tags: c#, oop, object

In C# i have a class called myclass now ,

I'm creating a object like this,

```
myclass myx = new myclass();
```

then

```
myx = new myclass();
```

It's not giving any error but what this means .....

Comment: It is from the same type myclass. This operation is like a reset for your object myx.

Comment: Why would you expect an error?

Comment: The code is fine. Why are you expecting an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you are creating yet another instance and assigning it to your variable, effectively "abandoning" the first one you created with new.

The garbage collector will know to clean the old one at some point. You can no longer access it, since you did not save it to another variable.

Answer (score 3):

It means you are throwing away the first myclass instance and creating a new one. There may be other code between that is doing something with the first one, like adding it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

`myclass myx = new myclass();` this line has declaration and initialization both

but

`myx = new myclass();` this has only initialization, of an previously declared object

if you want an error then remove `myclass myx = new myclass();` from your code, and yo will get an error for sure. In short `new` keyword is used for any object's initialization but that object has to be declared first, which can be done either on same line or can be done somewhere else after object's declaration.

For more info on `new` [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`myx` is a reference to an instance (object) of your `myclass`.

With `myclass myx = new myclass();` you tell your reference `myx` to point to an object created with `new myclass()`.

As references are reusable, when you write `myx = new myclass();`, that reference (`myx`) stops pointing to the old instance of `myclass` and now points to the new one you just created.

Since noone else points at the old one, garbage collector is activated (not immediately, but don't worry about that) and it removes the old `myclass` object from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know there are two different type of objects in .Net languages Reference Typed and Value Typed.(class vs struct) .Net manage each type differently.When you set a reference type to a variable as it name implies a reference to the memory address of that object is held in the variable but when you set a value typed object (a struct such as int , long and ...) to a variable you are actually holding the value in variable.
Thus in this scenario :

```
var a=new MyClass();
var b=a;
```

If MyClass is a class both a and b are referring to same object on the memory otherwise both have different values therefore if we do something like this :

```
a.Value=5;
```

a.Value==b.Value will be true if MyClass is a reference type and will be false if it's a value typed object
Now to answer you question either you are setting your variable myx to a new reference of MyClass (if it is a class)or you are setting a new value of MyClass in it (if it's a struct)
When you do something like this you have something that no one needs anymore (the old setting of myx) and will be garbage collected the next time the GC tries to clean the memory.